# Add Team to my account: Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Trying to add the team to my account, an error happened in this URL: [https://stackoverflow.com/c/[mycompanyname]/auth/saml2/post](https://stackoverflow.com/c/%5Bmycompanyname%5D/auth/saml2/post)

[image: error]

Comment: Note that the community and mods can't do anything about this and this needs staff handling. You might also want to use [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) as an alternative method.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was filed to our Support Team via the Contact Us form. We subsequently were able to analyze the issue and come to a resolution with the user. The cause is mostly a very narrow edge case that affected only this user (in fact two separate reasons for two separate means of receiving the error).

The "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page is a generic error, though. As noted, detailed information on the error is automatically recorded on our end, which allows us to figure out what may have specifically occurred if we stare at the given instance (easiest with knowing the exact page and the time it was delivered). But that detailed information is only recorded on our end - so the page *on its own* is not a sufficient means to match the issue from others who also run into the page - it could be caused by a completely different reason, especially if one runs into it from a separate page or process than the other.

In the case of issues on the public sites that deal with public information, it remains handy to post about it because people can cross-reference how they ran into the page and determine an overall matching use case. But when it reaches certain elements of Teams and account information, it stalls because much of the information (including even disclosing what Team one belongs to) can be considered private details that cannot be provided in public channels like Meta. And without having that specific information available in a public report, it makes the question on its own not necessarily beneficial to other users who run into the same page on Teams. There was in fact another report of this page on Meta regarding Teams that I was apprised of, but the source of running into the page doesn't match the circumstances that affected this user. So linking them together wouldn't necessarily help either situation.

To that end, I recommend that if you run into the Oops Robots page in circumstances that involve information that can't be publicly disclosed (such as sensitive account details or matters pertaining directly to one's Team), please reach out to our Support Team via the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form instead. Perhaps we should update this page (I'm pretty sure this page and its advice are basically unchanged from as long as I've been a member of these sites) to not just point to Meta Stack Overflow, now that we've breached into operations that can't all be discussed within the scope of Meta.